# How to create a Static member inside a form in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I need to keep some object static (without change ) inside a form in vb 6. The object is passing to the form before form.Show vbModeless code block. There is a list inside this form and when item click event fires, the object becomes Nothing.

In my application, there is a class and a form. I need to use an object of the class inside the form. In the main calling class there's a sub method to load the form and call it's aainitialization method too.  I pass the SelectStyleDlg object to the form as follows.

Below I have mentioned the sub method that I am using in  the calling class.

```
Public Sub ShowTheDialog()  
With frmSelectStyle
 .aaInitialize SelectStyleDlg:=SelectStyleDlg
 .Show vbModeless
End With
End Sub
```

Now I am going to mention the code in the form.

```
Option Explicit
Private mobjSelectStyleDlg As SelectStyleDlg

Public Static Sub aaInitialize(ByRef SelectStyleDlg As SelectStyleDlg)
Set mobjSelectStyleDlg  = SelectStyleDlg 
End Sub 

Private Sub lvwStyles_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)

 If Not mobjSelectStyleDlg Is Nothing 
  MsgBox  "Object is not nothing"
 Else 
  MsgBox  "Object is nothing"
 End If
End Sub
```

When item click event fires the mobjSelectStyleDlg object becomes nothing. 
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Where is this code executed? If it's executed entirely inside an event procedure, your `objForm` will go out of scope when the procedure exits. `vbModal` would (temporarily) prevent that because it will hold a reference to the object.

Comment: you could disable the list box.  `listbox.enabled = false`. You can also provide some more code so that we can investigate further

Comment: Thank you both for your ideas. I have pass the related object when I calling the function. It solves my problem upto now. :) But I guess the way I do is not the perfect way like using Static member. Still I have no idea about how to use a static member in the VB 6.

Comment: Do you directly reference `frmSelectStyle` or is it stored in a variable somewhere?  Your first code sample before the edit should you used `new` on it, this one you are not.  The more details you leave out, the harder it is for us to help.

Comment: Now I Directly reference the frmSelectStyle form because when I used new, it creates a new frmSelectStyle  form for every single  click event of the button in the main form. It was identifies as  a bug. In this case if the loaded frmSelectStyle  form is not closed, no new form is loaded.

Comment: Looking at just the code you have posted now, I cannot see why `mobjSelectStyleDlg` would become null (`Nothing`).  i suggest defining the `Form_Initialize` and the `Form_Terminate` events in the `frmSelectStyle` form and put breakpoints there to see if the form is getting removed from memory.  Another thing to check, are you sure when you call `.aaInitialize SelectStyleDlg:=SelectStyleDlg` that SelectStyleDlg is not nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean static, I think you just need a class instance variable.

Within your form:

```
Private mSelectStyleForm As frmSelectStyle

Private Sub cmdSelect_Click()

   If mSelectStyleForm Is Nothing Then
      Set mSelectStyleForm = New frmSelectStyle 
   End If
   Call mSelectStyleForm.aaInitialize(SelectStyleDlg:=SelectStyleDlg) 
   Call mSelectStyleForm.Show(vbModeless) 'Or Modal

End Sub

Private Sub MyForm_Unload()
   If Not mSelectStyleForm Is Nothing Then
      'depending on if you unload the form earlier or not, do that too here
      Set mSelectStyleForm = Nothing
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @tcarvin , In my application there is a class called SelectStyleDlg and a form called frmSelectStyle. I need to use a object of SelectStyleDlg class inside the form.  Currently I am passing that corresponding object to the form via form.aaInitialize method like I mentioned in the question. When I use vbModal parameter to show the form, that object is nicely exists in the form. But when I use vnModeless parameter , the object's reference is missing or lost. That's why I am thinking of a way to keep a static object. What is your idea ? Thank you.

Comment: You need to show more code for more help.  The code you posted isn't even in a Sub or Function, and it is not possible to tell where that code lives (is it in a form or a class)?  How does it get called.  Also, if the aaInitialze is the problem, please post that code too.

Comment: Hi @tcarvin, I have edited the question with more details. Please have a look.